# How to get DataGridView Cell current font and style

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In a CellFormatting or CellPainting event handler of a DataGridView I'm setting the Font (to be bold) and Color (Fore and Background) of a cell.

```
    private void DataGrid_CellFormatting(object sender,   DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }

    private void DataGrid_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

This works as expected and the desired font and colors are properly displayed. Later I'm trying to read the font and colors from the cells but they appear to be empty.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGrid.Rows)
{
    Font font = dgvr.Cells[0].Style.Font;
    Color foreColor = dgvr.Cells[0].Style.ForeColor;
    Color backColor = dgvr.Cells[0].Style.BackColor;
}
```

Font is always null and colors are empty.

Where are they stored and how can I access them?

Comment: It seems that the `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs.CellStyle` is only used temporarily to format the cell. So when you overwrite them, the `DataGridViewCell.Style` stays as it is. I'm not sure it's easily possible to get the color defined in the `CellFormatting` event from the cell itself. Maybe define the `DataGridViewCell.Style` instead of using the `CellFormatting` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CellFormatting` event of the `DataGridView` control is raised during methods which request for formatting, like when painting the cell or getting `FormattedValue` property. The `CellStyle` which you change will not apply on the cell and just will be used for formatting value and painting, so you can not find those styles outside `CellFormatting` event.

*Source Code:* [`DataGridViewCell.GetFormattedValue`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewCell.cs,dfcfbf2744d48cec) method is the central method which cause `CellFormatting` event be raised and if you take a look at source code of the method, you can see the changes which you apply on `CellStyle` is not stored in cell.

**Solution**

As an option to solve the problem, you can raise the `CellFormatting` event yourself when you need and use the result of formatting. To do so, you can create such extension method for `DataGridViewCell`:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
public static class DataGridViewColumnExtensions
{
    public static DataGridViewCellStyle GetFormattedStyle(this DataGridViewCell cell) {
        var dgv = cell.DataGridView;
        if (dgv == null)
            return cell.InheritedStyle;
        var e = new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs(cell.RowIndex, cell.ColumnIndex,
            cell.Value, cell.FormattedValueType, cell.InheritedStyle);
        var m = dgv.GetType().GetMethod("OnCellFormatting",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null,
            new Type[] { typeof(DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) },
            null);
        m.Invoke(dgv, new object[] { e });
        return e.CellStyle;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the method this way:

```
var s = dataGridView1.Rows[].Cells[0].GetFormattedStyle();
var f = s.Font;
var c = s.BackColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var e = new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs(cell.RowIndex, cell.ColumnIndex,
            cell.Value, cell.FormattedValueType, cell.InheritedStyle)
```

`rowindex` and `columnIndex` are swapped, but works great after change